Pyinstaller - Include images from local package
I am trying to package a python app with pyinstaller as a single file.
This app calls a custom package, installed locally, containing images. The structure of the package is the following:
mypackage
 |--src
   |--mypackage
     |--widgets
       |--icons
     |--otherfolder

I managed to add the custom package to the .exe using:
a = Analysis(
    ['my_app.py'],
    pathex=['absolute_path_to_my_package'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=added_files,
    hiddenimports=['seaborn'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)

The package itself is included but the icons are not included despite adding each file of the icons folder to:
added_files = [
    ('abolute_path_to_first_icon', '.'),
    ('abolute_path_to_second_icon', '.'),
]

Can someone explain me why the icons are not included in the .exe file?
